# MagentoEE/CE 1.x - about SKU

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

I'm curious about one thing, and I'm currently not able to check it...

Is the SKU an unique id in the whole Magento application, or does the Magento recognizes SKU as unique ID per website?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.anyknowledge.com/magento-what-is-sku-all-about/

... Magento uses `SKU` **(Stock-Keeping Unit)** as a unique identifier / code for each & every product, **across all stores & website**s. ...

Comment: SKU is a global attribute, and therefore the same for all sites. Each product also has an ID which is global as well.